# I need help formatting an HTML/CSS Email Signature

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, email-signature

I used a free online HTML signature creator but now my always emails land in junk folders when I use the signature.

I read online that the code needs to be formatted correctly to avoid being labeled as spam.

Here's how the signature looks and should look:

[image: signature screenshot]

and here's my code (I had to remove all links to avoid my question being marked as spam):

```html
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size:0;height:24px;line-height:0;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;font-family:Arial;line-height:1.15;color:#000;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="height:1px;width:91px;vertical-align:top;padding:.01px 1px;">
              <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align:top;padding:.01px;width:91px;text-align:center;">
                      <a href="website" style="display:block;" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noreferrer"><img src="logo" height="90" width="91" style="width:91px;vertical-align:middle;border-radius:0;height:91px;"></a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>

              </table>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" style="padding:.01px 0.01px 0.01px 18px;vertical-align:top;">
              <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="line-height:1.32;padding-bottom:18px;;font-family:Arial;"><span style="text-transform:initial;font-weight:bold;color:#62738C;letter-spacing:0;line-height:1.92;font-size:20px;"> First Last Name </span><br><span style="text-transform:initial;font-weight:;color:#62738C;line-height:1.2;font-size:14px;"> Astrobnb | Host Services </span></td>
                    <td style="vertical-align:bottom;">
                      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;" align="right">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td style="padding:.01px 0.01px 18px 50px;">
                              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td align="left" style="padding-right:6px;text-align:center;padding-top:0;">
                                      <a href="fb" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noreferrer"><img width="28" height="28" src="fb-icon" style="float:left;border:none;" border="0" alt="facebook"></a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left" style="padding-right:6px;text-align:center;padding-top:0;">
                                      <a href="ig" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noreferrer"><img width="28" height="28" src="ig-icon" style="float:left;border:none;" border="0" alt="instagram"></a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left" style="padding-right:6px;text-align:center;padding-top:0;">
                                      <a href="yelp" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noreferrer"><img width="28" height="28" src="yelp-icon" style="float:left;border:none;" border="0" alt="yelp"></a>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="padding:.01px 0.01px 18px 0.01px;border-bottom:solid 1px #45668E;border-top:solid 1px #45668E;">
                      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;width:100%;">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td nowrap="" width="383" style="padding-top:18px;white-space:nowrap;width:383px;font-family:Arial;">
                              <p style="margin:.1px;line-height:1;">
                                <span style="font-size:12px;color:#62738C;white-space:nowrap;">
                                                   <img src="phone-icon" style="vertical-align:-2px;line-height:1.2;width:13px;" width="13"><!--[if mso]><span>&nbsp;</span>
                                <![endif]--><a href="tel:555-555-5555" target="_blank" style="font-family:Arial;text-decoration:unset;" rel="nofollow noreferrer"><span style="line-height:1.2;font-family:Arial;color-scheme:only;color:#62738C;white-space:nowrap;"> 555-555-5555</span></a> &nbsp; <img src="web-icon" style="vertical-align:-2px;line-height:1.2;width:13px;" width="13"><!--[if mso]><span>&nbsp;</span>
                                <![endif]--><a href="website" target="_blank" style="font-family:Arial;text-decoration:unset;" rel="nofollow noreferrer"><span style="line-height:1.2;font-family:Arial;color-scheme:only;color:#62738C;white-space:nowrap;"> astrobnb.co</span></a> &nbsp; <img src="email-icon" style="vertical-align:-2px;line-height:1.2;width:13px;" width="13"><!--[if mso]><span>&nbsp;</span>
                                <![endif]--><a href="mailto:email@email.com" target="_blank" style="font-family:Arial;text-decoration:unset;" rel="nofollow noreferrer"><span style="line-height:1.2;font-family:Arial;color-scheme:only;color:#62738C;white-space:nowrap;"> email@email.com</span></a>
                                                   
                                                </span>
                                             </p>
                                          </td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                 </table>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>         <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="max-width:600px;width:100%;">
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td style="line-height:0;"></td>
      <span style="display: block; text-align: center;">    <br>    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="website" color="#45668E" class="sc-eqIVtm kRufpp" style="border-width: 6px 100px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(36, 160, 237); display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(36, 160, 237); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: 500; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; line-height: 30px; font-size: 15px; border-radius: 20px;">Book a Cleaning Today!</a>
                     </table>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               
            </tbody>
         </table>
```

I’m not well versed in HTML/CSS, I’m very new to it so I’m unsure of how to clean up the code and how to correctly format it.

When I remove the signature from my test emails, my messages land in the appropriate inbox.

Comment: start with the correct format of HTML that also include head and body

Comment: I read somewhere that the head is removed by some email clients, and to not include it, but I guess it was incorrect.

Comment: @tacoshy when I try to submit my new edits, I get this error: Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon. 

And even after adding the Ctrl+K shortcut, it still does not let me publish

Comment: when you edit you have preview and can edit the codesnippet from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do consider following points while adding raw HTML in email or creating email templates:

Sloppy HTML tends to be characteristic of spammers, spammers are busy spamming, so they don't have the time and resources to test their email code to make sure the content renders well.

While issues with your email rendering and broken HTML might not cause your emails to end up in spam right away, they can annoy your subscribers or they might find your message suspicious and hit the dreaded “mark as spam” button as a result.

Also an email HTML is NOT equal to Web HTML.
There are a lot of obvious HTML tags and CSS attributes that are not supported by major email clients.

The button of the form will require you to use JavaScript (which is a problem).

Most email clients simply don't support flash content as it is considered unsafe for something as sensitive as email. Email clients block emails containing flash. You can use GIFs as an alternative to make your emails more appealing.

Spam filters and more importantly firewalls always take a "better to be safe than sorry" approach. So, all your well-intentioned emails with any type of script will go straight to the SPAM folder.

If your email has different versions of HTML and plain text email or broken HTML, then your emails will go into the spam folder.

Broken HTML will appear sloppy and unreadable on almost all email clients. Not only will users mark your email as SPAM, but it will also alert SPAM filters (they will think you could be a lazy spammer using unsophisticated tools).

Try this and see if this works or else you can modify the HTML as per your need

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Email Template</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size:0;height:24px;line-height:0;"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;font-family:Arial;line-height:1.15;color:#000;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="height:1px;width:91px;vertical-align:top;padding:.01px 1px;">
                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align:top;padding:.01px;width:91px;text-align:center;">
                          <a href="website" style="display:block;" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noreferrer">
                            <img src="logo" height="90" width="91" style="width:91px;vertical-align:middle;border-radius:0;height:91px;">
                          </a>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
                <td valign="top" style="padding:.01px 0.01px 0.01px 18px;vertical-align:top;">
                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="line-height:1.32;padding-bottom:18px;;font-family:Arial;">
                          <span style="text-transform:initial;font-weight:bold;color:#62738C;letter-spacing:0;line-height:1.92;font-size:20px;"> First Last Name </span>
                          <br>
                          <span style="text-transform:initial;font-weight:;color:#62738C;line-height:1.2;font-size:14px;"> Astrobnb | Host Services </span>
                        </td>
                        <td style="vertical-align:bottom;">
                          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;" align="right">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td style="padding:.01px 0.01px 18px 50px;">
                                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td align="left" style="padding-right:6px;text-align:center;padding-top:0;">
                                          <a href="fb" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noreferrer">
                                            <img width="28" height="28" src="fb-icon" style="float:left;border:none;" border="0" alt="facebook">
                                          </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left" style="padding-right:6px;text-align:center;padding-top:0;">
                                          <a href="ig" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noreferrer">
                                            <img width="28" height="28" src="ig-icon" style="float:left;border:none;" border="0" alt="instagram">
                                          </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left" style="padding-right:6px;text-align:center;padding-top:0;">
                                          <a href="yelp" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noreferrer">
                                            <img width="28" height="28" src="yelp-icon" style="float:left;border:none;" border="0" alt="yelp">
                                          </a>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="padding:.01px 0.01px 18px 0.01px;border-bottom:solid 1px #45668E;border-top:solid 1px #45668E;">
                          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;width:100%;">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td nowrap="" width="383" style="padding-top:18px;white-space:nowrap;width:383px;font-family:Arial;">
                                  <p style="margin:.1px;line-height:1;">
                                    <span style="font-size:12px;color:#62738C;white-space:nowrap;">
                                        <img src="phone-icon" style="vertical-align:-2px;line-height:1.2;width:13px;" width="13">
                                        
                                        <a href="tel:555-555-5555" target="_blank" style="font-family:Arial;text-decoration:unset;" rel="nofollow noreferrer">
                                          <span style="line-height:1.2;font-family:Arial;color-scheme:only;color:#62738C;white-space:nowrap;"> 555-555-5555</span>
                                    </a> &nbsp; <img src="web-icon" style="vertical-align:-2px;line-height:1.2;width:13px;" width="13">

                                    <a href="website" target="_blank" style="font-family:Arial;text-decoration:unset;" rel="nofollow noreferrer">
                                      <span style="line-height:1.2;font-family:Arial;color-scheme:only;color:#62738C;white-space:nowrap;"> astrobnb.co</span>
                                    </a> &nbsp; <img src="email-icon" style="vertical-align:-2px;line-height:1.2;width:13px;" width="13">

                                    <a href="mailto:email@email.com" target="_blank" style="font-family:Arial;text-decoration:unset;" rel="nofollow noreferrer">
                                      <span style="line-height:1.2;font-family:Arial;color-scheme:only;color:#62738C;white-space:nowrap;"> email@email.com</span>
                                    </a>
                                    </span>
                                  </p>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="max-width:600px;width:100%;">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td style="line-height:0;"></td>
                          <span style="display: block; text-align: center;">
                              <br>
                              <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="website" color="#45668E" class="sc-eqIVtm kRufpp" style="border-width: 6px 85px; width: -webkit-fill-available; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(36, 160, 237); display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(36, 160, 237); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: 500; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; line-height: 30px; font-size: 15px; border-radius: 20px;">Book a Cleaning Today!</a>
                      </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Such beautifully written code. I filled in the correct links and the messages were still landing in junk mail. 


So, to further troubleshoot, I tried the signature from a different workspace paid business email, and the signature worked perfectly without landing in spam. 

My guess is that since I’m using a mail forwarder for a free hostgator email from the astrobnb domain, that is what is causing the issue. I will have to purchase another Google workspace account for this domain to avoid landing in spam. 

I greatly appreciate you taking the time to re-format.

Comment: Can you try once again with updated code, I removed some comments from above HTML template.

Comment: I just finished updating links and testing your latest code, unfortunately it's still landing in spam, but I truly believe it's becuase I'm using gmail to send hostgator webmail with a signature. As I stated, when I test the siganture from a google workspace paid business account, it works flawlessly (with your first iteration of the re-formatted code) So thank you!!

Comment: One question I did have is, how do I avoid the text in the button formatting like this when viewed in mobile? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S96LOuFOWfWbpqaKdFa8KtnTJc1MoE4W/view?usp=share_link there is enough space for the text to not have to wrap, but it jumps to the second line for some reason

Comment: Okay, I have edited the answer to match button text size issue.